# Firestore + NgRx + Entities

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, ngrx-store, ngrx-effects

I'm struggling  with Ngrx + Firestore. I'm using a [tutorial code](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rv37jBygQ2g) for my app and everything works perfectly. 
The problem comes when I want to add another "query" action to my CRUD actions. I've set everything up (the new action & the new Effect) but I don't know what to do with the reducer and the `public contests: Observable<Icontest[]>  = this.contestStore.select(_fromcontest.selectAll);` bit.

My goal is to have one query that gets all documents, and another query that gets only documents that match a criteria (filtered query).

part of contest.actions.ts

```
export const QUERY = '[contest] query contests';
export const QUERY_MINE = '[contest] query my contests';

[...]

// Initial Query
export class Query implements Action {
  readonly type = QUERY;
  constructor() {}
}

// Query only my contests
export class QueryMine implements Action {
  readonly type = QUERY_MINE;
  constructor() {}
}
[...]

export type contestActions =
  Query | QueryMine | Added | Modified | Removed | Update | Create | Delete | CreateSuccess | UpdateSuccess | DeleteSuccess | Failure ;
...
```

part of contest.effect.ts

```
@Effect()
  query$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$.ofType(contestActions.QUERY).pipe(
    switchMap(action => {
      return this.afs.collection<IContest>('contests').stateChanges();
    }),
    mergeMap((actions: DocumentChangeAction[]) =>  actions),
    map( (action: DocumentChangeAction) => {
      return {
        type: `[contest] ${action.type}`,
        payload: {
          id: action.payload.doc.id,
          ...action.payload.doc.data()
        }
      };
    })
  );

  @Effect()
  queryMine$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$.ofType(contestActions.QUERY_MINE).pipe(
    switchMap(action => {
      return this.afs.collection<Icontest>('contests', ref => {
        return ref.where('owner', '==', this._auth.cachedUser.uid);
      }).stateChanges();
    }),
    mergeMap((actions: DocumentChangeAction[]) =>  actions),
    map( (action: DocumentChangeAction) => {
      return {
        type: `[contest] ${action.type}`,
        payload: {
          id: action.payload.doc.id,
          ...action.payload.doc.data()
        }
      };
    })
  );
...
```

and contest.reducer.ts is:

```
export const contestAdapter = createEntityAdapter<IContest>();
export interface State extends EntityState<IContest> { }
export const initialState: State = contestAdapter.getInitialState();

export function contestReducer(
  state: State = initialState,
  action: actions.contestActions) {

    switch (action.type) {

      case actions.ADDED:
        return contestAdapter.addOne(action.payload, state);

      case actions.MODIFIED:
        return contestAdapter.updateOne( {
          id: action.payload.id,
          changes: action.payload,
        }, state);

      case actions.REMOVED:
      return contestAdapter.removeOne(action.payload.id, state);


      default:
      return state;
    }
  }

      // Create the default selectors
      export const getContestState = createFeatureSelector<State>('contests');

      export const {
        selectIds,
        selectEntities,
        selectAll,
        selectTotal,
      } = contestAdapter.getSelectors(getContestState);
```

To get all documents, I call `contestStore.dispatch( new _contestActions.Query())` and to get only my documents I call `contestStore.dispatch( new _contestActions.QueryMine())`
However, how can I assign the results of each query to a different variable, let's say:

- `public contests: Observable<Icontest[]> = this.contestStore.select(_fromcontest.selectAll );`
- `public mycontests: Observable<Icontest[]> = this.contestStore.select( ????? );`
  ?

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query$ effect will load all entities. So you do not need a new query action, but you need a new selector.

To create a new selector, you need to create a space in the state to store the uid that can be referenced.

```
export interface State extends EntityState<IContest> {
  currentUserUid: string;
}
```

and new action:

```
export const LOGIN = '[contest] login';

export class Login implements Action {
  readonly type = LOGIN;
  constructor(public payload: string) {}
}
```

new reducer's case:

```
case actions.LOGIN:
  return { ...state, currentUserUid: action.payload };
```

new selector:

```
export const getCurrentUserUid = createSelector(
  getContestState,
  state => state.currentUserUid
);

export const getMine = createSelector(
  selectAll,
  getCurrentUserUid,
  (contests, currentUserUid) =>
    contests.filter(contest => contest.owner === currentUserUid)
);
```

usage:

Dispatch the Login action when you log in.

```
public mycontests: Observable<Icontest[]> = this.contestStore.select(_fromcontest.getMine);
```

**ps.** I recommend creating an AuthStore.

Comment: You're a life saviour!! Thanks a lot !
just for info, I'm coupling ngrx with Firestore (which has a Auth module)
Care to explain a litlle more about AuthStore?

Comment: after actually trying your solution, I have 3 remarks I hope you can help me with:

1 - My userID is comming from an Observable from a Service. How can do I pass this value to the ngrx selector o action or redux?

2- With that technique, filtering the 'contests' is done by the filter method of the Array class. Imagine I had thousands of these complex objects, this won't be efficient. If I prefer the database to do the filtering, how should I proceed?

3- Could you explain a litlle more about AuthStore?

Thx again for the help

Comment: 1. You can subscribe to Observable in your AuthService and dispatch to the store whenever a change is detected.

Comment: 2. If you are querying directly to the database, you can get the results in another state. [check](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/example-app/app/books/reducers/index.ts)
3. If you create an AuthStore that stores user information and whether you are logged in, instead of using AuthService, You better fit the purpose of using Redux. [check](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/tree/master/example-app/app/auth)

Comment: Ok, but where do I pass the value of "user ID"?

Comment: For AuthService: Subscribes the observable user variable and dispatches it to the store.
For AuthStore: There is already a userId in state.